# Multiple using statement with same connection/transaction... - .NET

Tags: .net, transactions, connection, using

I want to do 2 methods, one to do the insert of only one register, and other to do the insert os many registers (a list).

But i want the second method to call the first method, just to use the same INSERT code.

Is there a way to use the connection opened in the second method, in the first method, so i can call a rollback for all?

```
Shared Sub Gravar(ByRef Pessoa As Pessoa)
    Try
        Using con As New myConnection
            con.Open()
            If Pessoa.Id = -1 Then
                Insert(Pessoa, con)
            Else
                Update(Pessoa, con)
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub

Shared Sub Gravar(ByRef Pessoas As List(Of Pessoa))
    Try
        Using con As New myConnection
            con.Open()
            con.OpenTransaction()
            For Each Pessoa As Pessoa In Pessoas
                Gravar(Pessoa)
            Next
            con.Commit()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work - the single and multiple methods both create their connections and pass the connection to a 3rd method that does the work:

```
Shared Sub Gravar(ByRef Pessoa As Pessoa)
    Try
        Using con As New myConnection
            con.Open()
            _Gravar(Pessoa, con)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub

Shared Sub Gravar(ByRef Pessoas As List(Of Pessoa))
    Try
        Using con As New myConnection
            con.Open()
            con.OpenTransaction()
            For Each Pessoa As Pessoa In Pessoas
                _Gravar(Pessoa, con)
            Next
            con.Commit()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub

Private Shared Sub _Gravar(ByRef Pessoa As Pessoa, ByVal con As myConnection)
    Try
        If Pessoa.Id = -1 Then
            Insert(Pessoa, con)
        Else
            Update(Pessoa, con)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```